# How to return object from service to component in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular7, angular-forms

I want to access particular json in ngOninit. So i have id on click in edit button and with the help of that id i am getting complete object from database like form name , form json which etc. So from the service i want to return that json to ngOninit.

Here is service.

```
    GetFormById (id: number) {
    return this.httpClient.get<FormTemplate[]>(this.API_URL + 
    "GetFormTemplate/" + id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
    }
```

In console i am getting complete object from database which i have save.

Here is component

```
    ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    var json = this.dataService.GetFormById(+id);
    }
```

like how can i get json in ngOnInit.

**Edit**

```
ngOnInit() {
const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.dataService.GetFormById(+id).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
  const temp = response['TemplateJson'];
     })

initJq();
  var formData = '[{"type":"header","subtype":"h1","label":"Inquiry"},{"type":"paragraph","subtype":"p","label":"Paragraph content"},{"type":"text","label":"First name","name":"text - 1554220470561","value":"Vipul","subtype":"text"},{"type":"date","label":"Date Field","className":"form - control","name":"date - 1554220484446","value":"2019 - 04 - 25"},{"type":"button","label":"Send Inquiry","subtype":"button","className":"btn btn - primary","name":"button - 1554220480284","style":"primary"}]';

  this.formBuilder = (<any>jQuery('.build-wrap')).formBuilder({ formData });

 // Sample code to handle promise to get for data on page load directly
  this.formBuilder.promise.then(formBuilder => {
    console.log(formBuilder.formData);
  });
}
```

like whatever json i got in temp i want to pass it in var formData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how you should subscribe from observables. You should read up the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables)/[tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) when it comes to handling asynchronous operations (such as HTTP requests). Meanwhile, this is how we can fix your issue.

On your service,

```
GetFormById (id: number) {
  return this.httpClient.get<FormTemplate[]>(`${this.API_URL}GetFormTemplate/${id}`);
}
```

On your component.ts, we return the observable value by calling the `subscribe()` method.

```
ngOnInit() {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.dataService.GetFormById(id).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    const templateObj = response.TempleteJson;
  })
}
```

Comment: I am getting this object in console {Id: 24, TemplateName: "school management", TemplateJson:"[↵{↵"type": "header",↵"subtype": "h1",↵"lab…"button-1554701441337",↵"style":"primary"↵}↵]", CreatedOn: "2019-04-11T00:00:00", UpdatedOn: "2019-04-24T00:00:00"} so how can i access TempleteJson from this object on ngOnit

Comment: @RonakDumaniya nice, you are returning something. Ok, what exactly do you want to do with the JSON data? Do bear in mind that you can treat it as a JavaScript object. (E.g. response.Id)

Comment: can i able to store it in variable like var json = response.TempleteJson

Comment: Yes, you may store the object as a variable. Do something like `const templateObj = response.TempleteJson;` To test that it works, you can run `console.log(templateObj)`

Comment: I am getting error like TempleteJson dose not exist in FormTemplete[]

Comment: Try using `response['TempleteJson']`?

Comment: Are you sure `TemplateJson` is the right name? Is it nested within another object?

Comment: const temp = response['TemplateJson']; how can i access this temp outside subscribe like i want to store this temp in another var which is outside subscribe

Comment: You can't. You have to handle it within the `subscribe` block. You can either return it later, or you chain it with other RxJS methods

Comment: Please help me like how can i return ? if you have reference then please give me

Comment: Wait, just to check, do you need the TemplateJson immediately? Or is it used somewhere later? Can you tell me more when is it used?

Comment: I have edit code so can you give me solution based on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191590/discussion-between-wentjun-and-ronak-dumaniya).

Comment: please check this issue becuase of this i am stuck and this is final issur

Answer (score 2):

You don't subscribe to the `Observable` in the service class, but instead in the component:

In the service, just return the `Observable` from your service method:

```
GetFormById (id: number): Observable<FormTemplate[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<FormTemplate[]>(this.API_URL + "GetFormTemplate/" + id);
}
```

In the component you subscribe to the `Observable` returned by the service method:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.dataService.GetFormById(+id).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: I am getting this object in console {Id: 24, TemplateName: "school management", TemplateJson:"[↵{↵"type": "header",↵"subtype": "h1",↵"lab…"button-1554701441337",↵"style":"primary"↵}↵]", CreatedOn: "2019-04-11T00:00:00", UpdatedOn: "2019-04-24T00:00:00"} so how can i access TempleteJson from this object on ngOnit

Answer (score 0):

Don't subscribe inside service, subscribe inside component onInit.

```
GetFormById (id: number) {
    return this.httpClient.get<FormTemplate[]>(this.API_URL + "GetFormTemplate/" + id);
}

ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.dataService.GetFormById(+id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: I am getting this object in console {Id: 24, TemplateName: "school management", TemplateJson:"[↵{↵"type": "header",↵"subtype": "h1",↵"lab…"button-1554701441337",↵"style":"primary"↵}↵]", CreatedOn: "2019-04-11T00:00:00", UpdatedOn: "2019-04-24T00:00:00"} so how can i access TempleteJson from this object on ngOnit