# error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, http, post, rxjs

error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '{}'.
Service file :

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders,HttpResponse  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Person } from './person';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'


import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
    baseURL: string = "http://localhost:3000/api/persons/";

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
 
  
 addPerson(id,name)
    {

      var obj={};
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();  
        formData.append('id',id);  
        formData.append('name',name);   

        this.http.post(this.baseURL + "addPerson?token",formData).pipe(map(data => {
          alert(data);
          return data;
         
        }));

        return obj;
      }
    }
```

Component file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Person } from './person';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'httppost';
   people:Person[]=[];
  person = new Person();

formData:any = {};


  
  constructor(private apiService:ApiService) {
    this.formData.ID =""; this.formData.Name= "";
  }
 
  ngOnInit() {

  }
 

  addPerson() {
    this.apiService.addPerson(this.formData.ID,this.formData.Name).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
       
      })      
  }
}
```

have service file in which i have to call my api to get the api's and when i am going to subscribe the method in the other class where i am calling that service method  then its showing the error that the property "subscribe " does not exist on type {}

Comment: You are not returning the Observable from your service method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to mention that using `var` is not a good practice anymore, so you should consider refactor everything to use `let` or `const` (for more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)). 
Secondly, using Typescript without any types or only `any` as type are also not good practices because you're losing all beneftis of Typescript.

Let's have a look on your current code:

```
addPerson(id,name)
  {
    var obj={};
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();  
    formData.append('id',id);  
    formData.append('name',name);   

    this.http.post(this.baseURL + "addPerson?token",formData).pipe(map(data => {
      alert(data);
      return data;
    }));

    return obj;
  }
```

Your function declaration does not contain any types, based on the names I assume they are of type `string`. The `id` could be of type `number` as well. 
The return value of your function is `Object` because you're returning your `obj` and not the expected `Observable` because of that you're getting the eror `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '{}'.` (for more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55605849/how-to-return-object-from-service-to-component-in-angular)).

To make your code you need to adjust your code as following:

```
// I've added typings but they're not necessary to make it work
addPerson(id: string | number, name: string): Observable<Person> {

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();  
    formData.append('id', id);  
    formData.append('name', name);   
    
    // Return here your HTTP request <- This will make it work
    return this.http.post<Person>(this.baseURL + "addPerson?token",formData)
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                return data;
            })
        );

}
```

By returning the HTTP request the return value and type of your function is `Observable<Person>`, so the subscription within your component will work as expected.

Based on your comment, the type for `Person` could look like this:

```
export interface Person {
    id: string | number;
    name: string;
}
```

Since I don't know your data model I cannot be more specific with the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your service method should return an Observable to use subscribe, right now it is just returning an object, should be something like

```
 addPerson(id,name): Observable<Person> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Person>(this.baseURL + "addPerson?token",formData);
  }
```

Comment: error TS2740: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Person>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.

return obj;

in service file

Comment: It's just a sample request, you need to use the correct data model

Comment: since i'm new to this concept, can u give me the correct data model